# how can i make this donut pie chart(created with Raphael js) clockwise

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am beginner to Raphael. Actually the donut start anti-clockwise
I have a http://jsfiddle.net/fahim/dNp24/ how can i make this clockwise.

```
 function sector(cx, cy, r, startAngle, endAngle, params) {
        var x1 = cx + r * Math.cos(-startAngle * rad),
            x2 = cx + r * Math.cos(-endAngle * rad),
            y1 = cy + r * Math.sin(-startAngle * rad),
            y2 = cy + r * Math.sin(-endAngle * rad),
            xx1 = cx + r2 * Math.cos(-startAngle * rad),
              xx2 = cx + r2 * Math.cos(-endAngle * rad),
              yy1 = cy + r2 * Math.sin(-startAngle * rad),
              yy2 = cy + r2 * Math.sin(-endAngle * rad);
        return paper.path([
            "M", cx, cy, 
            "L", x1, y1, 
            "A", r, r, 0, +(endAngle - startAngle > 180), 0, x2, y2, 
            "L", xx2, yy2,
              "A", r2, r2, 0, +(endAngle - startAngle > 180), 1, xx1, yy1, 
            "z"])
         .attr(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm understanding you right from the code you've pasted, but could reverse the order of the html tags. You can also change the angle var to where it starts from.

Otherwise you could do something like the following...

```
$( $("tr").get().reverse() ).each(function () {...
```

Updated fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/dNp24/2/